# SearchBar moves when active

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a SegmentedControl, UITableView and a UISearchController.  The SegmentedControl is at the top of the main View with the tableView just beneath it.  The searchController's searchBar is placed in the tableView.tableHeaderView and looks like this:

[image]

When the searchBar is tapped (made active) it moves down leaving a gap just above:

[image]

Also, if the searchBar is active and then the segmentedConrol is tapped (filtering the table data and reloading the tableView) then the tableView loads but with a gap at the top.  (I have purposely set the searchBar to hidden when the 'Category' filter is selected.

[image]

If the segmentedControl 'Category' is selected when the searchBar is not active this is how it looks (and should look):

[image]

I need two things (I think they are related), 1) for the searchBar to NOT move when active and 2) for the searchBar to not be present when 'Category' is selected and for the tableView to have no gap at the top.

.h:

```
@interface ExhibitorViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>
{
    // DATA
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfExhibitors;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfExhibitorsFiltered;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfCategories;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfCategoriesFiltered;

    // VARS
    int selectedSegment;
    float searchBarHeight;
    float tableViewY;
    NSString *currentCategory;
    CGRect tableViewStartRect;

    // UI
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
    UIView *categorySelectedView;
    UIView *headerView;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sponsorsOnly;

@end
```

.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    if (selectedSegment == 0) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = FALSE;
    }
    if (!_searchController.searchBar.superview) {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    }
}

-(void)loadTableView
{
    [self printStats:@"loadTableView START"];
    searchBarHeight = self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height;
    Settings *settingsInstance = [Settings new];

    if(!_tableView) {        
        segmentedControl = [UISegmentedControl new];
        segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Exhibitor", @"Category", nil]];
        [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 35)];
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
        //self.definesPresentationContext = NO;

        float tvX = self.view.frame.origin.x;
        float tvY = self.view.frame.origin.y + segmentedControl.frame.size.height;
        float tvWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        float frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
        float tvHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - segmentedControl.frame.size.height;
        tableViewStartRect = CGRectMake(tvX, tvY, tvWidth, tvHeight);

        _tableView = [UITableView new];
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]     initWithFrame:tableViewStartRect];
        //_tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0);
        _tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

        [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
        [_tableView setTag:1];
        [_tableView setDataSource:self];
        [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    }

    if (!categorySelectedView) {
        float levelOneStart = (0);
        categorySelectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, levelOneStart, self.view.frame.size.width, (screenHeight * 0.05))];
        [categorySelectedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [categorySelectedView setTag:4];
        MyLabel *catSelectedLabel = [[MyLabel alloc]     initWithFrame:categorySelectedView.frame];
        [catSelectedLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[settingsInstance getFontSizeFor:@"Label"]]];
        [catSelectedLabel setTag:5];
        [catSelectedLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightTextColor]];
        [catSelectedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        UIButton *categoryBackButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth * 0.6), levelOneStart, (screenWidth * 0.4), (screenHeight * 0.05))];
        [categoryBackButton setTitle:@"^ Back ^" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [categoryBackButton setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [categoryBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resetTableViewCategories) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [catSelectedLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetTableViewCategories)]];
        [categoryBackButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[settingsInstance getFontSizeFor:@"Label"]]];
        [categorySelectedView addSubview:catSelectedLabel];
        [categorySelectedView addSubview:categoryBackButton];
        [categorySelectedView setHidden:TRUE];
    }

    if (!headerView) {
        headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (0), screenWidth, (searchBarHeight))];
        [headerView addSubview:categorySelectedView];
        [self.view addSubview:headerView];
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:headerView];
    }

    [self.view setTag:11];

    tableViewY = _tableView.frame.origin.y;
    [self printStats:@"loadTableView END"];
}

-(UISearchController*)searchController
{
    if (!_searchController) {
        _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
        _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
        _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
        [_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    }

    return _searchController;
}

-(void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue
{
    [self.searchController setActive:NO];
    if ((segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)) {
        selectedSegment = 0;
        currentCategory = @"";
        [self resetTableViewExhibitors];
        [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
    } else {
        selectedSegment = 1;
        [self resetTableViewCategories];
        [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
        //[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 56) animated:NO];
        [_tableView setTableFooterView:nil];
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have tried changing the insets of various views and forcing a manual changes to the frames of various views (this is the closest thing to a fix but seems very hacky).  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  Have also tried :

```
-(void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue
{
    [self.searchController setActive:NO];
    if ((segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)) {
        selectedSegment = 0;
        currentCategory = @"";
        [self resetTableViewExhibitors];
        [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
    } else {
        selectedSegment = 1;
        [_searchController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion^() {
            [self resetTableViewCategories];
            [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
            [_tableView setTableFooterView:nil];
        }];
    }
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to dismiss `_searchController` or deselect `_searchController.searchBar` when tapping segment?

Comment: I simply made the searchBar either hidden or moved it.  Do you mean to remove the _searchController / searchBar (as a view) altogether and then rebuild when the segmented control is tapped again (to the main filter)?

Comment: I mean `[_searchController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];` and you can change to segment 2 in completion block

Comment: When I add that function call and wrap the contents of the segmentedControlValueHasChanged for the second segment the searchBar now fills the gap in the 'Category' filtered side of the tableView (added edit to question).

Comment: Did you remove `[self.searchController setActive:NO];` when try it?

Comment: I didn't initially but then I did.  Now if I click on 'Category' the searchBar is visible on the tableView (it should be) but when I tap the searchBar (set it to active) on the first tab of the segmentedControl AND THEN select 'Category' the tableView loads the categories WITHOUT the seachBar (so this is now correct).  I just need to make sure the searchBar is NOT available when 'Categories' are selected AND that the searchBar does NOT move when set to active.

Comment: Because you use `UISearchController` so it will always move when active. To avoid it, use `UISearchBar`. And when you use `UISearchBar`, it's easy to hide when you select `Category tab`

Comment: @trungduc Put this as an anser and I will accept it as this is what I ended up doing.  My tableView and searchBar work perfectly with my segmentedControl now.

Comment: It's great when you resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `UISearchController` so `searchBar` will always move when it actives. To avoid it, use `UISearchBar`. And when you use `UISearchBar`, it's easy to hide when you select `Category tab`

Comment: I stopped using a UISearchController and just used a UISearchBar instead and everything is working fine now.